# remove title-style automatic mousehint on html element

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit

How can I remove the automatic mousehint that appears when you hover over an element in some browsers?

I have this effect...

[image]

...when I hover an ellipsis span.
This is a default behaviour in safari.
How can I prevent the yellow browser mouse hint? (as I'm already implementing my own one)

This is no title tag, it's just a stripped (ellipsis) span.
I tried cursor actions in css but this also affects hover functionality.

this is the span html :

```
<span alt="&lt;em&gt;E&lt;/em&gt;5.b Promotion des investissements destinés à prendre en compte des risques spécifiques, garantie d?une résilience aux catastrophes et développement de systèmes de gestion des situations de catastrophe"><em>E</em>5.b Promotion des investissements destinés à prendre en compte des risques spécifiques, garantie d?une résilience aux catastrophes et développement de systèmes de gestion des situations de catastrophe</span>
```

I use the alt attribute to store the mousehint appearing in the white box.

This is the hover function in jquery:

```
$(document).on({mouseenter: function(event) 
    {  
      event.preventDefault()
      var dest = $("#footer");
      if(  $(this).parent().attr('id') ==  'topmenu' ) dest = $("#headerHint");
      if(  $(this).parent().hasClass('limeui-limetreeview-bar') ) { dest = $("#mouseInfo"); dest.fadeIn(20)  }

      console.log(dest);

      dest.html($(this).attr('alt'));
    },mouseleave: function(event)
    {
      $("#footer").html('');
      $("#headerHint").html('');
      $("#mouseInfo").html('').fadeOut(50);
    }}, "[alt]");
```

Comment: Can you add some code here. I mean your html and css.

Comment: Is it mandatory to store that message in alt attribute.? If not store it in some other data-attribute, Your problem will be solved.

Comment: isn't it the title attribute that triggers the yellow box? not the alt attribute?

Comment: @VincentDuprez http://accessibility.psu.edu/imageshtml please read this.!

Comment: @VincentDuprez read about `alt` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). So there is no point to use `alt` attribute in span element. And yes `alt` attribute can be shown as [tool tip](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) in IE for `img` tag.

Comment: I removed both alt and title, still appearing, this has nothing to do with these attributes, it's because of the ellipsis css rule. When the string is not truncated, it's not showing the yellow tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `event.preventDefault()` function call in your event handling. And if your element have `title` attribute remove it. See following **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rr2m5/3/)**.

I guess your problem came from title attribute of 'a' tag. So you should remove it for all your links where you want to prevent it as following code snippet:

```
$('a').attr('title', '');
```

So, if you want to stop showing your title attribute of link elements try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').mouseover(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title', $this.attr('title'));
        // Using null here wouldn't work in IE, but empty string will work just fine.
        $this.attr('title', '');
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('title', $this.data('title'));
    });
});
```

In above case your storing your title attribute data to data-title attribute temporarily.

Comment: Just tried (see the added js code), but doesn't changes anything, thanks

Comment: If you open demo you can see. There is two link elements with title and without title you can do something similar.

Comment: I see, but there is no title attribute in my code, the tooltip comes from the fact the string is truncated by css ellipsis.

Comment: It is really interesting can you make code available in public network? Or if it is possible can you make jsFiddle test page? Because i wonder what can cause this kind of problem.

Comment: as this topic was getting out of control and with downvotes, I made a new question with jsfiddle and plain explanation, narrowed down the problem to only one browser : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974276/css-ellipsis-prevent-tooltip-in-safari