# Prevent Safari from showing tooltip when text overflow is hidden with ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, tooltip

How can I completely remove the default browser tooltip displayed when hovering over a truncated part of text in a link?

Text is truncated because of a css ellipsis rule :

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

When I apply these rules to a fixed width div, I get a html tooltip. (**Only in Safari**, not in Firefox or Chrome.)

Here is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m9he/1/).

I tried adding a JS `preventDefault` and adding an empty `title` attribute, but none of these work.

Comment: Your fiddle is not set up right... Guessing this a OSX type of thing, seeing no tooltip on windows.

Comment: @epascarello have you tried in safari on windows?

Comment: Have not had that installed in years... Did you try setting an empty title attribute on the element?

Comment: yes i tried.. no result

Comment: Did you find the solution/workaround to prevent the native tooltip? Please share it in case.

Comment: no, I didn't find any solution.

Comment: @manoj please find the workaround in hon2a's answer. I know I'm 6 years late but still... :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ability to show tooltips for elements with text overflow cut off with ellipsis that don't have a non-empty `title` is part of WebKit core, but it's turned off by default. Only Safari overrides that and has the behavior enabled. There's no way to turn that off from your application code.

As a work-around, add an empty block element inside the element that has the overflow hidden with `text-overflow: ellipsis`. This can be done either for real, as @bas's answer already shows, or by creating a pseudo-element with CSS:

```
&::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

(using SCSS syntax). If you use Sass and create a mixin encapsulating the hiding of text overflow with ellipsis, this can be a nice addition without the need for any extra HTML mark-up.

Comment: `::after` should be used instead of `::before`, otherwise, `overflow` & `text-overflow` of the container will not going to work on IE and Edge.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. And yes, `::after` should be used to make it work on all browsers.

Comment: @jfroy I just found out the root cause and abstracted a clean version of the work-around. But if I had to guess, I'd guess the native tooltips can only show _text_ and can only safely infer that from inline content.

Comment: This totally breaks if you're using a `<button>` tag. The ellipsis just goes away. The ellipsis still shows up on Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 7):

I was also not allwed to use `pointer-events:none`, because it is a link. I was inspired by the answer of user1271033. The examples did not work for me, but adding an empty div before the text inside the truncated div worked for me.

Example:

```
    <div style="text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;width:50px;">
         <div></div>
         Test test test
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this http://schoonc.blogspot.ru/2014/11/safari-text-overflow-ellipsis.html ? Maybe it will be suit you. Examples:

```
<div class="text-container">longlonglonglongname</div>
.text-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    ...
    &:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
    }

<div class="text-container" data-name="longlonglonglongname"></div>
 .text-container {
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     ...
     &:before {
         content: attr(data-name);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the tooltip in Safari by setting pointer-events: none; in the CSS. Be aware though, this disables all pointer events, so if it's a link, then the link will disable as well.

Answer (score -1):

Add css in your code

```
 pointer-events: none;
```

Even you can create new css for it and apply wherever required.

You can do it in this way :

```
<div id="fix" title=""><a href="http://www.google.com"><span style="pointer-events:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></a></div>
```

Have a looke

https://jsfiddle.net/poojagayake/tx06vq09/1/

Comment: thanks for digging out, unfortunately, this is a link, so it needs to be seen by the cursor and already was proposed by another answer

Comment: @VincentDuprez I use this from span and it work for me fine. I think, you should try at least once.

Comment: I run your code jsfiddle on safari browser and it work on my side.

Comment: I was speaking about the link, the link doesn't work anymore